# Full node shows a different datetime(hour) value than the same field in a view

Tags: 8, datetime

I have a content type with a "date and time" field. I have populated this field using core json post using this format 2020-02-19T13:25:00. This works good and field is filled. When I add this field to a view, it shows the same date and time, but when I open the full node page, the time is one hour less, that is, It shows 2020-02-19 12:25:00. I have Spain/Madrid time zone. I have tried changing "field presentation" and twig template with `node.field_mydatetime.value|date('H:n:s','Europe/Madrid')` but without success. I don't know how to show the right hour, the same I have filled.

Comment: Instead of use the twig date filter, try rendering it through the field formatter set to a date format in Drupal, and update the template to have `{{ content.field_mydatetime }}`

Comment: Also confirm the value the database.  Probably `node__ field_mydatetime. field_mydatetime_value`, that it is the correct date/time at UTC.  I would need to look at the normalizer again, but it possible that your REST is getting interpreted in the wrong timezone, if it isn't specified in the POST.

Comment: I have checked the database field and the value isn't correct. It shows 2020-02-19T12:25:00 but I have posted 2020-02-19T13:25:00. It's strange, the view shows the right hour. Then I have to change the posted json in order to add time zone. I'm not sure how to do it.